# How to remove null elements from multidimensional array in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an arrayList  called `Arr_SxCorrel_table2d` like:
The ArrayList is of the type: `ArrayList<List<String>>`

```
Arr_SxCorrel_table2dREMOVAL[[OF, RE, RE, RE, IND], [HA, 22, 3, 1, 4, 18%], [HA, 7, 3, 1, 4, 57%], [REG, 3, 1, 0, 1, 33%], [BING, 4, 3, 33, 32, 23%], [], [NOTE: details.], [], [], []]
```

I want to get rid of the elements that are empty. I tried:

```
for (int i=0;i<Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.size(); i++) {
                 if (Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.get(i) == null){
                     Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.remove(i); 
                         }
                 }
```

But nothing gets removed. Not sure what the next step should be

Comment: There are no null elements in your lists.

Comment: So what are these []. Do they contain whitespace??

Comment: They can either be empty lists, or lists containing a single whitespace element. But you're obviously in a much better position to find out.

Comment: Could it contain a carriage return element. Is that possible so it would look as i does?

Comment: try also to check for the size of the ArrayList.

Comment: I don't think so. But you're really wasting your time asking me when you could easily debug and find out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code removes `null` references from the outer List, it doesn't remove empty Lists.

Try :

```
for (int i=0;i<Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.size(); i++) {
    if (Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.get(i) == null || Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.get(i).isEmpty()){
        Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.remove(i); 
        i--;
    }
}
```

Note that `i` must be decremented whenever you remove an element from the List, since the indices of the elements that follow the removed element are decremented.

Comment: OK but the elements are still not removed.

Comment: @SebastianZeki If the `[]` elements in the question represent empty inner Lists, they should be caught by the `Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.get(i).isEmpty()` condition and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check their size if they are more than 0 :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.size(); i++) {
    if (Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.get(i).size() == 0) {
        Arr_SxCorrel_table2d.remove(i--);
    }
}
```

There's no need to check if there is a null value because it will not compile if the variable is given a null value.